# Best practice for running a cron job inside an app on Openshift?

Tags: cron, openshift

I want to run a simple backup of my postgres db deployed in Openshift. What are the best practices for running a cron job? Since systemd is not available on the containers and can only be enabled through a hack, I'd rather use a 'cleaner' approach. Besides cronie or systemd timer units, what options are there? There seems one could enable cron in [earlier](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/openshift_enterprise/2/html/user_guide/scheduling_cron_jobs) Openshift versions, however Openshift v4.x doesn't support this feature anymore and the docs only mention the Kubernetes Cron Jobs objects.

Answer (score 6):

Here is what I use:

- Dedicated Pod with same image (ensure db dump client is available) and PVC for backup mounted
- ConfigMap with backup script
- Cronjob running that pod frequently

Here's some example manifests:

PVC:

```yaml
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
    metadata:
      name: database-bkp
      namespace: database
        annotations:
        volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-class: "storage-class-name"
    spec:
      accessModes:
        - ReadWriteMany
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 1Gi
```

CM:

```yaml
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: ConfigMap
    metadata:
      name: psqldump
      namespace: database
      labels:
        job-name: db-backup
    data:
      psqldump.sh: |
        #!/bin/bash
        DBS=$(psql -xl |awk /^Name/'{print $NF}')
        for DB in ${DBS}; do
          SCHEMAS=$(psql -d ${DB} -xc "\dn" |awk /^Name/'{print $NF}')
          for SCHEMA in ${SCHEMAS}; do
            echo "Dumping database '${DB}' from Schema '${SCHEMA}' into ${BACKUPDIR}/${PGHOST}_${SCHEMA}_${DB}_${ENVMNT}_$(date -I).sql"
            pg_dump -n "${SCHEMA}" ${DB} > ${BACKUPDIR}/${PGHOST}_${SCHEMA}_${DB}_${ENVMNT}_$(date -I).sql
          done
        done
        echo "Deleting dumps older than ${RETENTION} days"
        find ${BACKUPDIR} -name "*.sql" -mtime +${RETENTION} -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

CronJob:

```yaml
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Template
    metadata:
      name: postgres-backup
      namespace: database
    objects:
    - kind: CronJob
      apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
      metadata:
        name: postgres-backup
        namespace: database
      spec:
        schedule: "0 3 * * *"
        successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 1
        jobTemplate:
          spec:
            template:
              metadata:
                namespace: database
              spec:
                containers:
                - name: postgres-dbbackup
                  image: "postgres:11"
                  env:
                  - name: PGHOST
                    value: "${_PGHOST}"
                  - name: PGUSER
                    value: "${_PGUSER}"
                  - name: RETENTION
                    value: "${_RETENTION}"
                  - name: BACKUPDIR
                    value: "${_BACKUPDIR}"
                  command: ["/bin/bash", "-c", "/usr/local/bin/psqldump.sh"]
                  volumeMounts:
                  - mountPath: /usr/local/bin
                    name: psqldump-volume
                  - mountPath: /backup
                    name: backup-volume
                volumes:
                  - name: psqldump-volume
                    configMap:
                      name: psqldump
                      defaultMode: 0755
                  - name: backup-volume
                    persistentVolumeClaim:
                      claimName: database-bkp
                restartPolicy: Never
    parameters:
      - name: _PGHOST
        value: postgres
      - name: _PGUSER
        value: postgres
      - name: _RETENTION
        value: "30"
      - name: _BACKUPDIR
        value: "/backup"
```

PGHOST is the pod name of your data base. If you have a dedicated user and password for your backup, export the env vars PGUSER and PGPASS accordingly

Answer (score 2):

Running the cronjob inside the same pod as your db is not a good idea (the pod where the db runs can be killed/respawned etc)

IMHO the best solution is to define a Cronjob in the same project as the db, the Job will use an official OpenShift base image with the OC CLI, and from there execute a script that will connect to the pod where the db runs (`oc rsh..`) and perform the backup

Or execute a script from outside OCP that will connect to the cluster (with a system account), then execute`oc rsh <db pod name> <backup command>`

Comment: Thank you @titou10. Do you have an example of an OpenShift base image with the oc CLI installed? I assume you are referring to running the oc rsh command from within the cronjob.

Comment: yes: official OCP CLI image: registry.redhat.io/openshift4/ose-cli:v4.10